# Reporting predicted outcome of mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model, sas, reporting

I am analyzing some group-randomized longitudinal trial data with three time points using mixed effects model. Some people missed 1-2 time points, and I didn't exclude any cases with missing dependent variable prior to running the analysis. When I was asked by a colleague to report the predicted value, I hit into a problem:

Let's say the simple form of the regression model is:

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x1 + \beta_2 x2$

After estimating the regression coefficient, we can then find out the predicted y, $\hat{y}$. My question is, when calculating this predicted y, should I include cases that have a full set of predictors, but missing on the outcome? Is there any conventional rule to follow?

Thank you very much for your advice in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a classic MCAR/MAR/MNAR example. Have you looked at the relevant literature? I don't know a conventional wisdom rule but given you analyzed "*everything*" without being concerned for missing values, it feels a bit odd to start do this now.